# Error with django-compositekey package

Tags: python, django, composite-key

I need a composite key in my django project. I find [this projects](https://github.com/simone/django-compositekey) and try use it.

```
class Loccupy(models.Model):

    id = db.MultiFieldPK('lolockcode', 'loroomcode', 'loindate', 'loopercd')

    lolockcode = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True,
    loroomcode = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True,)
    loindate = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True,)
    loopercd = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True,)
```

But I get a mistake:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
File "/home/.../lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 385, in execute_from_command_line
utility.execute()
File "/home/.../lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 354, in execute
django.setup()
File "/home/.../lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 21, in setup
apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
File "/home/.../lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 108, in populate
app_config.import_models(all_models)
File "/home/.../lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 202, in import_models
self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
File "/home/.../.pyenv/versions/2.7.10/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
__import__(name)
File "/home/.../models.py", line 133, in <module>
class Loccupy(models.Model):
File "/home/.../lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 282, in __new__
new_class._prepare()
File "/home/.../lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 306, in _prepare
opts._prepare(cls)
File "/home/.../lib/python2.7/site-packages/compositekey/db/models/fields/wrap.py", line 13, in _prepare
for prepare_action in getattr(opts, "_lazy_prepare_field_actions", []): prepare_action()
File "/home/.../lib/python2.7/site-packages/compositekey/db/models/fields/multiplekey.py", line 71, in lazy_init
cls._meta.unique_together.append(names)
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'append'
```

What is a reason this mistake? I write my code, exactly in readme example.
Maybe, it is a another package for adding composite key?
And I need a composite key, not unique_together. I have a existing database? with only this four column, and no one of this column do not unique. Only all four columns may be a unique.

Comment: It looks like the package isn't compatible with the version of Django you are using. It appears that Django 1.6 compatibility was not completed, and the last commit was nearly a year ago.

Comment: You have a missing parenthesis on line `lolockcode = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True`. @Neri can you fix that if it's not a typo and re-try?

Comment: Yes, i use Django 1.7, apparently this is a problem.  Missing parenteses is a typo. In my file it is all right.